# Get the users birthday within a date range

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I want to get the list of users who has a birthday of 3 days before and after todays date. What I mean is, if today is `March 2,2013`, I want to get the users who have birthdays starting `Feb 27,2013` upto `March 5,2013`. This is my database design.

**Users table**

```
id | name | birth_day | birth_month | birth_year
```

I can no longer change the database design since I have no access on it and changing the design will only occur to a huge changes on the website.

This is my current code:

```
if (empty($date))
            $date = date('Y-m-d'); // now

        $start_date = strtotime($date.' -'.$day_range.' day');
        $end_date = strtotime($date.' +'.$day_range.' day');
        $start_month = date('m', $start_date);
        $end_month = date('m', $end_date);
        $start_day = date('d', $start_date);
        $end_day = date('d', $end_date);

        if ($start_day > $end_day) {
            $tmp = $start_day;
            $start_day = $end_day;
            $end_day = $tmp;
        }

        /* This is a dirty fix for getting birthdays between dates */
        $this->User->contain(array('User' => array('first_name', 'last_name', 'userstatus_id')));
        $user = $this->User->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.birth_month BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($start_month, $end_month),
                'User.birth_day BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($start_day, $end_day),
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                'birth_year',
                'birth_day',
                'birth_month'
            ),
            'order' => array(
                'birth_month' => 'ASC',
                'birth_day' => 'ASC'
            )
        ));

        foreach($user as $k => $v) {
            $temp = strtotime(date('Y-'.$user[$k]['User']['birth_month'].'-'.$user[$k]['User']['birth_day']));

            if ($temp >= $start_date && $temp <= $end_date) {
            }
            else {
                unset($user[$k]);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Why are you storing the birth date is three separate columns?  Doing it this way means to have to generate the date every time you need it.  If you store it as a datetime, then you already have the correct value.

Comment: You should be storing birthday as a timestamp and using INTERVAL

Comment: @bluefeet That is part of the challenge on this question. I have no access on changing the database design and if i'll change it will cause huge changes on the website.

Comment: Is `birth_month` a number or varchar?  Is it `3` for `March` or is it the name `March`?

Comment: @bluefeet Those are all numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cannot change your table design, then I would create a datetime from the three columns and then use that for a filter:

```
select *
from 
(
  select id, name,
    str_to_date(concat(year(now()), '-', birth_month, '-', birth_day), '%Y-%m-%d') birthdate
  from users
) d
where birthdate >= '2013-02-27'
  and birthdate <= '2013-03-05'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/764e5/2).

This uses the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) functions to create a birthdate as a date datatype.  Once you have the date, then you can apply your date filter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try this on out then i'll get back to you immediately. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Hmm, it's not giving me a correct result. Maybe the reason because your "WHERE" clause on the birthdate has this year's year(2013), we have users that were not born this year but today is their birthday.

Comment: @ElsonSolano see my edit, change the use of the `birth_year` to `year(now())` and it should work.

Comment: @ElsonSolano you are very welcome, obviously I was not thinking in my first version. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the date in alphabetic order so query year, month then day.  The problem there is the overlap at the start and end of the month.  Using [MySQL date formatting options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) you could concatenate your dates and convert them to a date object to search upon.  If you have many rows this will be slow and not efficient as each and every row must be evaluated.

The other way is to query the columns you already have but using a range condition worked out from application logic and generate inline SQL such as

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE 1=1
```

Then:

```
AND birth_year = X
```

OR for overlapping ranges

```
AND (birth_year = X OR birth_year = Y)
```

Do the same for birth_month and birth_day

Not an elegant solution, but given your poor schema design I can only see one of these two alternatives.  The first is easier but the 2nd should generally perform better provided the query isn't performing a full table scan - if you're not indexing then just use the string to date option.